# How to sum array values from a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, sum

How can I sum results from a for loop? I iterate over the loop 10 times and I want to add them together.

My output currently looks like this:

`4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048`

I would like add them thogether

```js
function przelicznik(){
    var first= parseFloat(document.getElementById("pierwszy").value); 
    var second= parseFloat(document.getElementById("drugi").value);
    var text="";

    for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        var a=first + second;  // 4=2+2    // 8=6+2 
        var b=first + a;       // 6=4+2    // 14=6+8
        first = b              // first=4  // first=8

        //result of 10 times loop put into 'var text'.
        text +=  a ;
    }
    document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=text;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="pierwszy">
<input type="number" id="drugi">
<input type="submit" value="przelicz" onclick="przelicznik()">


<div id="wynik"></div>
```

Comment: why text=""? maybe text = 0?

Comment: I can convert this into an actual answer, but do you have a class assigned to all of the values that you want to add?

Comment: I'm totally confused. Try to better explain what is the desired outcome of your code, and where are you stuck with it...

Comment: Could you please provide us with the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to accept 2 numbers from the user, then sum the output of a calculation 10 times and add it back to the page.

Hopefully the below will help you out.

```js
function przelicznik(){
  var first= parseFloat(document.getElementById("pierwszy").value); 
  var second= parseFloat(document.getElementById("drugi").value);
  var arr=[];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      var a=first + second;  // 4=2+2    // 8=6+2 
      var b=first + a;       // 6=4+2    // 14=6+8
      first = b              // first=4  // first=8
    
      //result of 10 times loop put into 'var text'.
      arr.push(a);
  }
  document.getElementById("wynik").innerHTML=arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="pierwszy">
<input type="number" id="drugi">
<input type="submit" value="przelicz" onclick="przelicznik()">
<div id="wynik"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,good job ,that was exactly what I wanted to do :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that sticks out to me is that you are appending your text variable with a however you are ending you logic with the first variable...would you not want

```
text += first;
```

As your last line in your for loop?  If your values are integers I'd also advise using parseInt rather than parseFloat.